# How to add the country of an users in the default FreeIPA schema

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I am trying to extend FreeIPA person schema to add the `country` field in the default user.

As far as I know, FreeIPA does implement the RFC 4519, which does provide a [country field][1].

When I dump the schema of FreeIPA (via `ldapsearch -x -b cn=schema objectclasses attributetypes > schema.ldif`) I see that the country definition is present by default, but it is not part of the person or any extension of the person.

So I have created the following ldif (note that the OID is basically random, I did not yet register anything since I am testing stuff around:

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: objectclasses
objectclasses: ( 2.25.2866739172111323825341701611583088740684.14.2.1 NAME 'customPerson' SUP person STRUCTURAL MAY (country) X-ORIGIN 'Extending FreeIPA' )
```

But when I run this via `ldapmodify8 I get the following error:

```
$ ldapmodify -D "cn=Directory Manager" -W -f customPerson.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
modifying entry "cn=schema"
ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: object class customPerson: Unknown allowed attribute type "country"
```

What did I do wrong, and how to fix it so that I can use the `country` field in all my users?
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519#ref-X.521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an answer after continuing to tinker on this.

Turns out the `country` is not an attribute, but an objectclass, so after adding `country` and `friendlyCountry` into the default IPA objectuserclasses (via IPA Server > Configuration > User Options), I then created the following update file:

```
dn: uid=test,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
add:c:CH
add:objectClass:country
add:objectClass:friendlyCountry
add:co:Switzerland
```

You need to define the `c` attribute has it is needed for both `country` and `friendlyCountry`.

I can now see this with the `ipa user-show  --all test` command.

Comment: But what you are adding now isn't a person, but a country. A better solution might be https://stackoverflow.com/a/21996393/1904815