# Minimal example of extending already existing API and CLI call in FreeIPA 4

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I am looking to add fields into the user definition in FreeIPA 4.4.

Right now I have [modified the user schema](https://serverfault.com/questions/808377/how-to-add-the-country-of-an-users-in-the-default-freeipa-schema) and added the fields in the Web UI for editions.

Now I would like to be able to change the new fields added (country code `c` and country name `co`) via the JSON API and thus via the CLI tool. This will require to changes already existing API call such as `user_add`, `user_show` etc.

I have found examples of such plugins but for FreeIPA 3, and it seems that the python API changed since then because those are not working when I adapt those with the good field name. I get the following error:

```
$ ipa
ipa: ERROR: ImportError: No module named plugins
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipalib/cli.py", line 1348, in run
    api.finalize()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipalib/plugable.py", line 707, in finalize
    self.__do_if_not_done('load_plugins')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipalib/plugable.py", line 422, in __do_if_not_done
    getattr(self, name)()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipalib/plugable.py", line 586, in load_plugins
self.add_package(package)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipalib/plugable.py", line 613, in add_package
    module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaclient/plugins/country.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ipalib.plugins import user
ImportError: No module named plugins
ipa: ERROR: an internal error has occurred
```

Is there a minimal example somewhere online of adding one or two new attributes to a user for FreeIPA 4.4?

Small precision, I know at least one example of [full-blown plugin that adds a whole new type of object](https://github.com/abbra/freeipa-desktop-profile), but as far as I get everything in there, it is not applicable in the case of adding new fields for an already existing object.